# Latency of establishing 1000 TCP/IP connections from client to server

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp, latency

I would like to make 1000 connections to a server. Only after all of the connections are made I would like to start sending or receiving data on the connections.

The server is trivial, it just accepts connections and then sequentially performs reads and writes. The server has a backlog of 8192 and blocks on a read from the 1st connection:

```
// Why doesn't backlog of 8192 allow the client to establish 1000 connections?
listen(serversocket, 8192);
while(1) {
    struct sockaddr_in client_addr;
    socklen_t client_addr_len = sizeof(client_addr);
    int fd = accept(serversocket, (struct sockaddr*)&client_addr, &client_addr_len);

    // This blocks the server on a read from the 1st connection
    short data1;
    read(fd, &data1, sizeof(data1));

    char data2[32];
    write(fd, data2, sizeof(data2));

    close(fd);
}
```

The client contains the following code:

```
int sockfds[1000];
int i;
for(i=0; i<1000; i++) {
    int sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    sockfds[i] = sockfd;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    bzero(&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(5678);

    connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    printf("%d: connected\n", i);
}

// ... read from sockfds[j], write to sockfds[j]
```

The first 130 connections are established in a few milliseconds. However, the connections 130...999 are being established very slowly at a rate of about 1 connection per second.

*What should client.c do in order to establish all 1000 connections in a few milliseconds? Why doesn't backlog of 8192 allow the client to establish 1000 connections?*

Comment: Why? Why not start using a connection as soon as you have it? Why 1000? Can the server really handle 1000 connections?

Comment: It is a server benchmark. Basically, the server starts with `listen(serversocket, 8192)` and then performs `accept(serversocket, ...)` in a while-loop.

Comment: I checked the server. It actually cannot handle 1000 connections, but I thought that having backlog of 8192 on the server will allow the client to make 1000 connections. Seems like the assumption in the previous sentence is incorrect.

Comment: Are you sure that the client is actually making connections? I see no error checking in that code.

Comment: @user3386109 Error checking is omitted from the code for the sake of brevity. The client works correctly, the only problem is that slowness after 130 connections.

Comment: @Atom Could you show the real code which demonstrates the problem please?  Just in case something that has been removed was responsible for the slowness.

Comment: I just looked at the man page for `listen`.  At the bottom, in the `Bugs` section it says, "The backlog is currently limited (silently) to 128."  That may or may not apply to your OS, but it seems to match the behavior that you're seeing.

Comment: @user3386109 You are right. I found it in the man page for `listen` as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to set /proc/sys/net/core/somaxconn to a value greater than 1000.

The default value is 128. This explains why the client experiences increased latency after making about 130 connections to the server.

Answer (score 0):

After accepting the connection, read & write has to be performed from a different thread so that the number of times accept call invoked will get higher. Read & write are blocking call & it will take some CPU time to complete. Move the socket read & write to different thread & then check the count of accepted connections.